# why @Asynchronous and Future Class does not work

Tags: asynchronous, jakarta-ee, future

I am trying to call asynchronous method that returns Future Object, I suppose that it will print YYY and then XXX since the XXX is in a method that is 1 sec long. however, after deploying the code, it did not work properly, I tried the same thing with 10 objects and they printed sequentially. where is the error

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testfuture;


import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;

@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TestFuture {

    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void start()  {

                try{
                    Future<String> r = inparallelMethod(5) ;
                    System.out.print("YYY");
                    r.get();
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException ie )
                {
                    System.out.print(ie.getMessage());
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e)
                {
                     System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }


        }

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> inparallelMethod(int i) throws InterruptedException
    {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("XXX");
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call inparallelMethod inside the instanced class "bybassing" container managmenet of calling an async menthod.

You have to define the async method in another bean, @Inject that bean and call the method.

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)    
public class TestFuture {

    @Inject
    AsyncService service;

    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void start()  {

                try{
                    Future<String> r = service.inparallelMethod(5) ;
                    System.out.print("YYY");
                    r.get();
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException ie )
                {
                    System.out.print(ie.getMessage());
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e)
                {
                     System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                }


        }
}

@Stateless
public class AsyncService {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> inparallelMethod(int i) throws InterruptedException
    {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("XXX");
        return null;
    }


}
```

I post the code to make work the async but your code in very poor to test an async scenario, Thread.sleep inside a java-ee is a very bad practice because thread are managed by container and you can't know wich thread you are really sleeping!